# Downloading resources before they are needed

Tags: gwt

I am developing an online multiplayer game using GWT and I want to reduce traffic by downloading images and sound files before they are utilized. I am using the method Image.prefetch for the image files. Is this the right way?

Concerning the sound files, I do not know exactly how to ensure that they are downloaded before the game starts. I am using the library gwt-voices and currently invoking the method play() on all needed sound files with a sound controller with default volume 0. 
In both cases, it seems like the files are fetched once and then cached. This is fine but I think it might be better to have them downloaded them by the client and access them locally - if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work with sound files but you may wish to use a ClientBundle. At compile time this will create a single large image so when you first ask for one of the images the client will retrieve the entire large image and then you ask for and get the individual images.  This cuts down on the multiple requests needed to otherwise retrieve each image individually.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle

Also, you should look into code splitting which would probably be useful as well.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't really aware of these two things. I think they could be really helpful, perhaps in combination with the profiling tools offered by Google.